# Simulink PID Flow Control Using Omega FC-22

Tags: controls, simulink

I am attempting to create a PID controller for an air hose and valve system. The system consists of an Omega FC-22 flow computer, a motorized valve, and a down stream sensor to measure cubic feet per minute (CFM). The control loop goes as follows: user punches in desired CFM -> valve turns until flow computer = desired CFM -> valve corrects itself when desired CFM exceeds +/- 1 (or so) CFM. The upstream airflow is not part of the control loop, once it is on, the valve is used to regulate it.

I understand how PID controllers work in Simulink, but am not sure how to go from a transfer function and PID controller to the scenario above. Also, another issue I face is figuring out how to interface the Omega FC-22 with Simulink, which is a critical portion. Any and all help is appreciated.

**I have attached the user guide for the Omega FC-22
https://www.omega.com/manuals/manualpdf/M2572.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make Simulink write the CV of the PID to the valve. Typically this is done via a 4-20mA signal from the controller (pc in your case). You'll probably have to see what types of input signals your valve supports and wire accordingly.

The PV of the PID will come from the flow computer's Modbus RS-485 interface. The manual didn't show a ModbusTCP or RS-232 option. You'll have to use an RS-232/RS-485 or a USB/RS-485 adapter. Then read in the appropriate flow from the modbus registers listed in Appendix C of the Omega manual.

The set point of the PID should be easy enough. Just have a way for the user to enter it on the pc and send that value to your Simulink code.